# Mathematical formula to a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I need to implement current formula.It is for scoring the nodes in a taxonomy. Basically, the score of a node depends on the amount of child nodes and their scores (`(nodes(h+1))` is the amount of nodes on the next level and `Cl(concept)` is a set of children).

[image: Formula]

In my usecase term frequencies are only defined for the leaves as of now. I have made an implementation, but the issue is that when there are 2 children for the node then the implementation only goes to one side.

For a given taxonomy:

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
   |   |
   4   17
  / \
 11 13
```

the frequencies are given: `freq(11) = 3`, `freq(13) = 5` and `freq(17) = 10`. When I try to get the score for `node(1)`, the result is `0.0`, because the recursion doesn't go into descendent `node(4)`, it retrieves only `freq(17)` and that's it. Normally, the result should be 7.

Here is the implementation:

```
public static float calcScore(int keyID, Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies, Map<Integer, Integer> subTaxonomy) {
    float res = 0f;
    int nodes = 0;
    if (frequencies.containsKey(keyID)) {
        return frequencies.get(keyID) + 0f;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : subTaxonomy.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() - 1 == subTaxonomy.get(keyID)) {
            nodes++;
            res += calcScore(entry.getKey(), frequencies, subTaxonomy);
        }
    }
    return 1 / nodes * res;
}
```

NOTE:

`subTaxonomy` - stores the nodeID and its level in the taxonomy

`frequencies` - store the frequencies for leaf nodes.

I also created a snippet at Ideone: [Source](https://ideone.com/kQegWQ)

How should I edit the code, so that it traverses all over the children for a given node?

**UPDATE**

So now, in updated source, it traverses all over taxonomy, but the result is 0.0 still.

Comment: To get children, you can get all nodes whose level is greater than the level of node you are interested in from the map right ?

Comment: @svasa yes, thats basically what I am doing. I get the level of the given node and while traversing I check all nodes that are on one level lower and consider them as children, i.e. I apply the method on that nodes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `subTaxonomy.put(17, 3);` ?

Comment: @c0der, yes! I have already updated the code and the snippet link. Had to be `(17,3)`, `(11,4)`, `(13,4)`. But still the result is 0.0

Comment: Do you mean `return 1 / (nodes * res);` ?

Comment: @c0der nope, I mean `return (1/nodes)*res`. The "penalizing" part before summation in the actual formula

Comment: your picture has a loose parenthesis in `nodes(h+1))`

Comment: @LeonardoPina yes, I noticed that. But, it doesn't change anything. So, shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: could you add a calculation of the desired result (7) ?

Comment: @c0der added the method.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit and posted it as a (wiki) answer. Questions shouldn't contain answers. You can answer your own question. If you wish to do this, let me know and I will delete the wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is located at this line of code

```
if (entry.getValue() - 1 == subTaxonomy.get(keyID)) {
```

The left part of your tree does not hold your intended convention that the `childs id` (which is not a leaf of the tree) follows the formula `childs id = parents id - 1`

I would suggest a change to your implementation including the `parents id` in your taxonomy instead of the `node level`. The level may be counted during recoursion and passed as another parameter.

New signature may look like this:

```
public static float calcScore(int keyID, Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies, Map<Integer, Integer> subTaxonomy, int level)
```

further you may consider to drop the `level` information from your code, if it doesn't contribute to your final result!

Comment: for sure! but `entry.getValue()` for node with `id==4` makes the recursion get stuck, because of the insufficient parent specification via `level`!

Comment: what kind of impact does the `level` have to your final result? maybe just leave it out?

Comment: Just was about to comment on that, while was going over the idea to store in the map `(child, parent)`. I don't need level at the end at all. I think, I can just provide a child id and then go further.

Comment: sounds good to to me! do not hesitate to contact me for further questions and klick the accept button ;)

Comment: Why are you  polluting the answer section? Why not just edit your first answer?

Comment: @S.M.Styvane Wrote answer, saw that i misunderstood, deleted answer, took a second closer look to the question (not yet knowing to manage the real problem solving), saw the real problem, wrote the correct answer to the question! What's wrong with this process?

Answer (score 1):

Copy of [OPs answer that was posted into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44262722/revisions)

CORRECT METHOD

```
public static float calcScore(int keyID, Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies, Map<Integer, Integer> subTax) {
    float res = 0f;
    int nodes = 1;
    if (frequencies.containsKey(keyID)) {
        return frequencies.get(keyID) + 0f;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : subTax.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == keyID) {
            res += calcScore(entry.getKey(), frequencies, subTax);
            nodes++;
        }
    }
    nodes--;
    return (float)1 / nodes * res;
}
```

NOTE

`subTax` - is the map containing `(child_id, parent_id)`

Comment: Don't blame me for that comment, but: is an answer without the proccess of solving the problem a valuable wiki content/answer? This may hold for problems/questions with "binary" answers, where e.g. a specification document draws you a clear answer, but i doubt, if its applicable here... (where the design is a key aspect)

Comment: @PrR3, my apologies. Normally I have accepted your answer, but then some of the moderators put my solution as an additional answer, and I, probably, accidentally clicked on accepted.

Comment: @Cap Absolutely no problem! A combination of both answers would be most valuable in my opinion.